# Вывод из базы данных по исключению

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, select

объясняю ситуацию, у меня на сайте есть поиск по жанрам и исключить жанры, все они  select multiple, я хочу сделать так чтобы при условии если человек выбрал какой-то жанр в исключение то все сериалы с этим жанром сразу отпадали

вот код обработчика php -

```
        $sjanrs = $_POST['sjanrs'];//Выбранные жанры
        $nosjanrs = $_POST['nojanrs'];//Жанры исключения

        array_walk($sjanrs, function (&$janr) {
        $janr = (int)$janr;
        });  
        unset($janr);

        array_walk($nojanrs, function (&$nojanr) {
        $nojanr = (int)$nojanr;
        });  
        unset($nojanr);

        $sjanrse = implode(',', $sjanrs);//Добавляем запятые

        $nosjanrs = implode(',', $nosjanrs);//Добавляем запятые

        $Result = mysqli_query($CONNECTDB, "SELECT `tid` FROM `janrs` WHERE `jid` IN ($sjanrse)");//Помощь нужна именно тут, как в этом запросе сделать исключение?

        while ($Glob = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result)) {
```

А это select он что в исключениях что в выбранных жанрах одинаковен

```
<select name="sjanrs[]" id="janrs" class="chosen-select" multiple data-placeholder="По каким жанрам искать">
                                <option                             value="1">
                    Альтернативная история
                </option>
                                <option                             value="2">
                    Альтернативная реальность
                </option>
                                <option                             value="3">
                    Ангелы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="4">
                    Андроиды
                </option>
                                <option                             value="5">
                    Антивойна
                </option>
                                <option                             value="6">
                    Антиутопия
                </option>
                                <option                             value="7">
                    Баскетбол
                </option>
                                <option                             value="8">
                    Безумие
                </option>
                                <option                             value="9">
                    Бисёнэн
                </option>
                                <option                             value="10"></select>
```

Comment: `NOT IN (1,2,3,4)`. Но это не будет работать как вы хотите. Если у фильма несколько жанров (комедия, боевик), а пользователь выбрал фильм комедия, но запретил боевик, то ему у него в выдаче появится этот фильм

Comment: понял, спасибо)